# Donde se almacenan los archivos .sql en windows?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

instalé MySQL en windows 10 64 bits y estoy probando las databases de ejemplo, descargue una que usan en un ejemplo que sigo, se llama northwind, no la tengo y la descargue de internet, la quiero incluir para que me aparezca para cuando haga un `show databases;`, pero no se donde colocar el archivo .sql que descargue. estoy desde la consola, pero puedo usar la workbench si es necesario

Comment: lo que tienes que hacer es importarla, no basta con que la guardes en una ruta; añade a tu pregunta si usas workbench o si estas desde la consola

Comment: estoy desde la consola, pero puedo usar la workbench si es necesario

Comment: si estas desde la consola bastaría con llevar a cabo el siguiente comando `SOURCE C:\Users\NombreUser\Desktop\respaldo.sql` donde tienes que colocar la ruta absoluta de donde se encuentra tu archivo sql con el nombre exacto y la ruta bien escrita, yo acabo de hacerlo con la misma base de datos que indicas y me quedó

Comment: por ejemplo yo me guarde la base de datos que deseo importar en el escritorio, por eso puse esa ruta, tu debes colocar la ruta donde guardes tu archivo .sql @darioxlz

Comment: @AlfredoPaz donde coloco el comando SOURCE?

Comment: cuando ya hayas iniciado sesión desde la consola de mysql, ahi lo escribe tal cual te pongo el ejemplo, solo escribe la ruta que te corresponde

Comment: te dejé una respuesta espero te sirva

Comment: No funciona el comando.....C:\Users\UsuarioName\Desktop\nombrebasedatos.sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desde la consola de mysql deberías hacer lo siguiente:

El siguiente comando es para conectarte primero al Gestor desde la consola

```
mysql -u root -p
```

posterior te pide la contraseña de tu usuario

```
******
```

Una vez hecho lo anterior ejecuta el comando en el siguiente orden

```
SOURCE C:\Users\UsuarioName\Desktop\nombrebasedatos.sql
```

> Debes escribir la ruta absoluta de donde se encuentra la ubicación del
>   archivo sql que tratas de importar, fijate que los nombre de todo
>   esten bien escritos

Deberías obtener en la consola información similar a la que a continuación te muestro

```
mysql> SOURCE C:\Users\UsuarioName\Desktop\nombrebasedatos.sql
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.05 sec)

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.11 sec)

Database changed
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.03 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.78 sec)

Query OK, 8 rows affected (0.15 sec)
Records: 8  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.05 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.69 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.06 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.48 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.05 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (1.43 sec)

Query OK, 91 rows affected (0.18 sec)
Records: 91  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.11 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.83 sec)

Query OK, 49 rows affected (0.10 sec)
Records: 49  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.05 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (1.31 sec)

Query OK, 9 rows affected (0.11 sec)
Records: 9  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.24 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 3 warnings (1.53 sec)

Query OK, 2155 rows affected (2.91 sec)
Records: 2155  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.07 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 4 warnings (2.38 sec)

Query OK, 376 rows affected (0.85 sec)
Records: 376  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Query OK, 377 rows affected (0.67 sec)
Records: 377  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Query OK, 77 rows affected (0.24 sec)
Records: 77  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.04 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 3 warnings (1.51 sec)

Query OK, 77 rows affected (0.25 sec)
Records: 77  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.09 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (1.15 sec)

Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.20 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.24 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (1.74 sec)

Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.30 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.17 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (1.79 sec)

Query OK, 29 rows affected (0.34 sec)
Records: 29  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.09 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (1.10 sec)

Query OK, 53 rows affected (0.41 sec)
Records: 53  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2):

Para cargar una base de datos MySql que está volcada en un fichero de texto y poder usarla se debe importar con una aplicación que permita trabajar con estas bases de datos. Puedes hacer la importación por consola, pero seguramente vas a querer hacer cosas con la BD y estas aplicaciones te facilitan muchas el trabajo. Suelo usar *phpMyAdmin* porque es sencillo. Si necesitas mas funciones, conexiones a bd remotas, virtualizadas, etc. es mejor *MySqlWorkbench*.

Si usas **phpMyAdmin** que viene con paquetes como *Xampp*, después de arrancar el servidor php + mysql, en el navegador puedes abrir: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/
verás la pestaña importar, ahi puedes cargar tu BD.

Si usas **MySqlWorkbench**, abre el programa. Deberás crear una conexión si no lo has usado antes. Hay que arrancar el servidor mysql y conectarse.
Aparece a la izquierda el cuadro "Schemas" con las bases de datos que tienes para la conexión. Crea uno nuevo para la base de datos a importar: clic en el cuarto botón bajo el menú (si dejas el puntero del ratón encima indica: Create a new schema in the connected server) le indicas el nombre y pulsas "Apply" te abre una ventana con el SQL para crear la BD, p.e. `CREATE SCHEMA`new_schema`;` Vuelve a pulsar "Apply".
Selecciona el esquema creado de la lista.
En el menú selecciona File / Open Sql Script...
Cuando cargas el script te abre el fichero con el SQL, lo seleccionas todo (Ctrl + Alt en windows) y lo ejecutas, el icono del rayo arriba.
Si el fichero SQL esta correcto debe añadir las tablas y datos a la base de datos creada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Editado:

Por cierto, acabo de buscar la BD que comentas: ***northwind*** y **es una base de datos para SQL server**, creo no vas a poder usarla con mysql.

Comment: te equivocas @Orici también existe para mysql esa base de datos, aquí la prueba http://fferegrino.blogspot.com/2011/10/northwind-en-mysql.html

Comment: Buena respuesta, pero quiero agregarla desde la consola, estoy usando la cmd de windows 10

Comment: @Alfredo Paz pa que te fíes de googe.